# Validation Required on button click not working JavsScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, validation

I am trying to add validation so when the upload button is clicked, if the textbox is empty then do not progress the progress bar and add a validation message. However, if there is a value in the textbox then progress the bar.

```
    function makeProgress(){
         if ($('#textbox').val() == '') {
             alert("Please upload a file.");
         }
         else
        {
        $("#pbarmain").show();
        $("#pbar").show();
        if(i < 100){
            i = i + 4;
            $(".progress-bar").css("width", i + "%").text(i + " %");
            setTimeout("makeProgress()", 100);
            }
            }


            <input type="text" id = "textbox" class="form-control" readonly>

  <button type="button" onClick="makeProgress()" class="btn btn-default" >Upload</button>
    <button type="button" id ="reset" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Comment: Add a `}` at the very end of your function, as your brackets don't match up otherwise.

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: Angelos - That didnt seem to work. It still progresses the progress bar and no alert appears.

Comment: please make a fiddle

Comment: where is i declared? and where is the progress bar

Comment: var i = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#reset").click(function() {
        $(':input','#attachmentModal').val("");
  $("#pbarmain").hide();
  $("#pbar").hide();
  i=0;
    });
});

Comment: it works, someone answered below. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to 'return false' for this one if you dont want the progress bar to proceed. This would stop the execution what was given on the [else] statement

```
if ($('#textbox').val() === '') {
    alert('Your alert message');
    return false; 
}
```

Hope this helps for you

Comment: No problem. Glad we could help. Please dont forget to vote accepted answers here. It helps for all of us.

Comment: Hi, how  do i do that? Im new to this

Comment: Click the large / small arrow up on the left side of a certain answer post. Reference: stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id = "textbox" class="form-control" readonly>
    <button type="button" onClick="makeProgress()" class="btn btn-default" >Upload</button>
    <button type="button" id ="reset" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function makeProgress(){
        if ($('#textbox').val() == '') {
            alert("Please upload a file.");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#pbarmain").show();
            $("#pbar").show();
            if(i < 100){
                i = i + 4;
                $(".progress-bar").css("width", i + "%").text(i + " %");
                setTimeout("makeProgress()", 100);
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the JavaScript code inside `<script></script>`

Keep in mind that `i` is not defined.
Same with the progressbar element and the other bars (`pbarmain` and `pbar`).

Also make sure to include Jquery in your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function makeProgress() {
      if ($('#textbox').val() == '') {
        alert("Please upload a file.");
      } else {
        $("#pbarmain").show();
        $("#pbar").show();
        if (i < 100) {
          i = i + 4;
          $(".progress-bar").css("width", i + "%").text(i + " %");
          setTimeout("makeProgress()", 100);
        }
      }
    }
</script>

<input type="text" id="textbox" class="form-control">
<button type="button" onClick="makeProgress()" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
<button type="button" id="reset" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLnemhhh/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id = "textbox" class="form-control">
    <button type="button" id ="reset" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close </button>
      <button type="button" onClick="makeProgress()" class="btn btn-default" >Upload</button>
      <div class="input-group col-xs-12"> <div class="input-group"> <label class="input-group-btn"> <span class="btn btn-primary"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Browse <input type="file" id = 'attachmentFileUploadInput' style="display: none;" multiple> </span> </label> <input type="text" id = "textbox" class="form-control"> </div> </div>
      <div class="modal-body"> <div id = "pbarmain" style="display: none" class="progress progress-striped active"> <div id = "pbar" class="progress-bar"></div> </div>
    <script>
    var i=0;
     var makeProgress= function (){
     console.log("in here");
             if ($('#textbox').val() == '') {
                 alert("Please upload a file.");
             }
             else
            {
            $("#pbarmain").show();
            $("#pbar").show();
            
            if(i < 100){
                i = i + 4;
                $(".progress-bar").css("width", i + "%").text(i + " %");
                setTimeout("makeProgress()", 100);
                }
                }
    }
    </script>
```